# Finding the number of unlabeled graphs with $n$ vertices such that each vertex has degree 2

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm trying to find the number of unlabeled graphs with $n$ vertices such that each vertex has degree 2. I know that the edge set for such a graph will have cardinality $n$ and that the maximum number of possible edges for any graph with n vertices is  ${n}\choose{2}$ but I'm not exactly sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Are the vertices labeled or unlabeled?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Was literally just about to ask that

Comment: Unlabeled...........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: A graph on $n$ vertices with each vertex having degree $2$ is simply a graph consisting of disjoint cycles. If the vertices are unlabeled, all you care about are the lengths of each cycle.

Comment: [A008483](http://oeis.org/A008483)